# Nonadjacent Multi Select in IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How many times have you had the following situation?

You have a switch or multiple if else like the following:

```
if (thisIsTrue)
{
     x = 1;
}
else if (thisIsTrueInstead)
{
     x = 2;
}
else if (thisIsSometimesTrue)
{
     x = 3;
}
else
{
     x = 4;
}
```

And you want to comment out nonadjacent code; like the following x = 2 and x = 4 are commented:

```
if (thisIsTrue)
{
     x = 1;
}
else if (thisIsTrueInstead)
{
     //x = 2;
}
else if (thisIsSometimesTrue)
{
     x = 3;
}
else
{
     //x = 4;
}
```

Is there a way to do a nonadjacent multi select in the IDE?

I find myself clicking, commenting, clicking, commenting, clicking, commenting a lot. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can enter multiple comments on different lines at once with the [MultiEditing](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2beb9705-b568-45d1-8550-751e181e3aef) extension.